# abstract class, all derived concrete classes should be singletons

Tags: java, singleton, abstract-class

I'm looking for best practices for the following design: I have an abstract class and every concrete class extending that abstract class should be a singleton.

Background: The concrete classes are collectors that compile and log statistics about the operation of a complex legacy system.  Collectors are accessible via a static registry, so there's no need to pass dependencies.  The abstract class provides the interface to the registry.

I'm aware that there's no perfect solution that gives guarantees, properties have to be maintained by conventions. Nevertheless, there might be best practices for this case.

Comment: this can't be done. You can, however, make it a protected class, so that only classes within the same package can implement it, and over those, you have the ability to check/alter the classes yourself if need be

Answer (score 1):

Technically you cannot prevent the concrete class to allow the creation of more than one instance of it.
But you have ways to try to conceptually enforce it :

- document clearly the interface
- set a constraint that require that these subclasses be beans managed by a dependency injection container

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to implement this, it is based on the following:

1. The constructors of the abstract class must have private visibility, so that it could be instantiated from inside only and to prevent it from being extended elsewhere.
2. The implementing singleton classes must be nested within the abstract class and must not be extendable.
3. The instances of the implementing nested classes are static members of the abstract class.

The drawback of this approach is that it can quickly become messy, due to nesting, especially if there are many implementations for singletons.

This might look as follows:

```
public abstract class AbstractEntity {

  public static final AbstractEntity SINGLETON1 = new EntityImpl1(); // might be also instantiated lazily

  /**
   * Private accessor will not allow this class to be extended from outside.
   */
  private AbstractEntity() {

  }

  static final class EntityImpl1 extends AbstractEntity {

    private EntityImpl1() {

    }

  }

  // other implementations...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my current solution

- singleton property is managed by the registry.  JavaDoc clearly states the correct and intended use
- a concrete instance is registered by a static `register(Instance.class, Instance::new)` method that has the class object and a supplier of instances of that class as arguments
- the registry maintains a map of String to instance objects, with the `toString()` result of the class object as key

Advantages

- instances can be private and can be placed close to the classes that using them (i.e., in the same package)
- instances are created once at first registry

Disadvantages

- instances are created by a constructor with empty parameter list
- the registry method needs two arguments